# Creating cumulative viewshed (non binary) using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, 3d-analyst, viewshed

In ArcGIS 10.2.For a viewshed calculation, as an input raster I have a DEM of an area. As an input feature a shapefile with 10 turbines.

Is it possible to create an output raster where the result is NOT just the "visible" or "not visible" one ?

I would like to create a raster that shows how many turbines are visible for each point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access to 3D Analyst or Spatial Analyst extensions, [Visibility](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Visibility/009z000000zr000000/) tool is your answer, which is defined as:

> Determines the raster surface locations visible to a set of observer
> features, or identifies which observer points are visible from each
> raster surface location.

Particularly, if you pick **Frequency** in *Analysis Type* parameter, it will produce what is visible (in overall, I think it uses OR operation) and how many times a specific cell is visible to observer points, without specifying which ones though.